# iterate over JSON array in react-native

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-native

I've come across a problem working in react native. I've parsed a JSON object and need to iterate over an array nested inside it.I want to get all `profiles` objects in a list.

i tried with the below code but its not fetching profiles object .how to print all profiles objects in  list?

code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Modal, Image, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { Spinner, Text, View, Content, Container,Item,Header,Body, Title, Button, Icon, InputGroup, Input, ListItem, List, Radio, CheckBox, Thumbnail, Card, CardItem, H3 } from 'native-base';

 class Profile extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            radio1 : true,
            check1: false,
            modalVisible: false,
            search: 'nativebase',
            selectedItem: undefined,
            results: {
                items: []
            }
        }
    }

    setModalVisible(visible, x) {
        this.setState({
            modalVisible: visible,
            selectedItem: x
        });
    }

    toggleCheck() {
        this.setState({
            check1 : !this.state.check1
        })
    }
    componentDidMount() {

        var that = this;
        this.search();

    }

    search() {
        // Set loading to true when the search starts to display a Spinner
        this.setState({
            loading: true
        });

        var that = this;
        return fetch('https://mysite.in/api/profilematch/25/')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                // Store the results in the state variable results and set loading to 
                // false to remove the spinner and display the list of repositories
                that.setState({
                    results: responseJson,
                    loading: false
                });

                return responseJson;
            })
            .catch((error) => {

                that.setState({
                    loading: false
                });

                console.error(error);
        });
    }

    render() {

        var that = this;
        return (
            <Container>
                <Content>
                <List>
                    {this.state.loading? <Spinner /> : <List dataArray={this.state.results} renderRow={(results) =>
                                <ListItem button onPress={()=>this.setModalVisible(true, item)} >
                                    <Thumbnail square size={80} source={{uri: results.avatar_url}} />
                                    <Text>Name: <Text style={{fontWeight: '600', color: '#46ee4b'}}>{results}</Text></Text>
                                     <Body>
                                    <Text>{results.sur_name}</Text>

                                    </Body>
                                </ListItem>
                            } />}
                </List>
            </Content>
            </Container>
         );
     }
 }
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    header : {
        marginLeft: -5,
        marginTop: 5,
        marginBottom: (Platform.OS==='ios') ? -7 : 0,
        lineHeight: 24,
        color: '#5357b6'
    },
    modalImage: {
        resizeMode: 'contain',
        height: 200
    },
    bold: {
        fontWeight: '600'
    },
    negativeMargin: {
        marginBottom: -10
    }
});

module.exports = Profile;
```

json:

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "profiles": [
            {
                "id": 18,
                "first_name": "sweta",
                 "is_active": true

            },
            {
                "id": 20,
                "first_name": "Hiteshi",
                 "is_active": true
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "first_name": "Sneha",
                "is_active": true
            }
        ],
        "user": 25
    }
]
```

All i want to do is to print `profiles` objects in a list.

Comment: `responseJson[0].profiles` is the array you want to iterate - so perhaps `results: responseJson[0].profiles` ?

Comment: @JaromandaX  Thanks a lot. its working  ,you saved my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While fetching add another variable

```
that.setState({
   //assuming profiles exist
   profiles: responseJson[0].profiles,
});
```

Creating a listview

```
<ListView dataSource={this.state.profiles} renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)} />
```

Displaying data

```
renderRow(rowData) {
   return (<Text>{rowData.first_name}</Text>);
}
```

I hope this helps you. Not tested but should work like this.